# Finish activity when back button pressed once

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my application I am facing this issue where an activity(ex:Activity_B) is getting closed only when back button is pressed twice.I want Activity_B to close when back button is pressed once and Activity_A to display after that.

I tried this code:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        //MoveTaskToBack(true);
        this.Finish();            
        Finish();
        FinishAndRemoveTask();
    }
```

But the behaviour is still same.
I tried putting debugger point and see how it behaves.
The Activity_B is getting called when back button is pressed.

The code to start Activity_B is :

```
 private void OnDataLayout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_B));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Update1: I observed that the OnDataLayout_Click event is also getting called twice and after navigating to OnCreate () of Activity_B, the OnCreate() is also getting called twice.

Comment: Which Activity opens first? `Activity_A` or `Activity_B`

Comment: Activity_A opens first then Activity_B. But when I press back button in Activity_B, Activity_B screen displays twice ,only then it navigates back to Activity_A

Comment: Would you please provide the code for starting Activity_B.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Please try to open new Activity using this `Activity_B.class` intead of `typeof(Activity_B)`.

Comment: Did you try putting `finish` after you call `startActivity`?

Comment: putting finish() is making the app to exit

Comment: Hello, by `Activity_B screen displays twice`, it means that there are two `Activity_B` instantiation? Could you please provide a demo for you question? Have you pressed the button twice?

Comment: Hii, Activity_B is instantiated only once. I have pressed the back button only once.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more code about where you bind the Click Event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OnDataLayout_Click event is also getting called twice

If your Button's click event was bound twice, the click event will be called twice.

Like below code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        initView();

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        initView();
    }
    private void initView()
    {
        Button bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt);
        bt.Click += Bt_Click;
    }

    private void Bt_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The `initView` method was called twice, `OnCreate` and `OnResume` method. This will cause your problem.

But, if you use `SetOnClickListener` method, the problem will disappear:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity,View.IOnClickListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        initView();

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        initView();
    }
    private void initView()
    {
        Button bt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt);
        bt.SetOnClickListener(this);
    }



    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to `Activity A` from `Activity B` `onBackpressed` you need not need to write any code for `backpressed` but if you want to exit on Backprssed from `Activity B` without going to `Activity A` then you need to `finish()` it in `Activity A();`